# using getPosition() and setPosition() in Lua with Gideros

Tags: lua, gideros

I am using SceneManager.:
Now, the problem is I have many objects on this level, but I want only one of them to move up and down on touch, the object is taken from texture pack and is basically an animation:

If i do `self:getPosition` and `self:setPosition`, all the objects in this level change their position, how do I change position of only `self.anim[frame]` when the user touches the screen?

--in Play.lua

```
self.anim = 
{
    Bitmap.new(pack:getTextureRegion("flappy1.png", true)),
    Bitmap.new(pack:getTextureRegion("flappy2.png",true)),
}
```

and then something like this :

```
self:addChild(self.anim[1])
self:addEventListener(Event.TOUCHES_BEGIN, self.whenTouched, self)
self:addEventListener(Event.TOUCHES_END, self.whenuntouched, self)

function Play: whenTouched()
  x,y = self:getPosition()
  self:setPosition(x, y-20)
end

function Play: whenuntouched()
  x,y = self:getPosition()
  self:setPosition(x, y+20)
  print("down")
end
```

Comment: could You please fix Your code indentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way would be to create separate layer for this animation like:

```
self.animationHolder = Sprite.new()
self:addChild(self.animationHolder)
self.anim = 
{
   Bitmap.new(pack:getTextureRegion("flappy1.png", true)),
   Bitmap.new(pack:getTextureRegion("flappy2.png",true)),
}
self.animationHolder:addChild(self.anim[1])
```

Then you would need to add/remove children from `self.animationHolder` to animate it (I would actually recommend using MovieClip for it, but that is another topic)

And when you set position for self.animationHolder, only animation will move, and not all objects on scene ;)

Comment: @artursosin: Oh, the layers. Right. Thanks :)